React app - gh-pages не находит мой js и css файл
gh-pages не находит мой js и css файл.
Выдает 404 ошибку, как итог - белый экран.

вот мой репозиторий -
https://github.com/Beliy14/Soc-Sec-online
Буду благодарен, если кто поможет!
